How to overwrite directory with code from the different branch
I have a git repository where we store front-end and back-end code - both in separate directories.
We are working on different branches, and sometimes, the front-end team has to get the back-end code.
The problem is these updates have a lot of code and it generates a lot of conflicts.
How to bring all of the code from the back-end branch into another branch just for a specific directory?
let's say we have 2 directories
project
  backend
  frontend

and we have 2 different branches: A-backend, B-frontend
We want to have all of the changes from branch A-backend in the directory /backend without resolving conflicts. And without resolving conflicts with "accept all theirs". We just want to overwrite the entire directory and keeps the history of the commits - so we don't want to copy and paste the code.

Check git help restore.

When you say "keeps the history of commits", you mean the history of commits of the branch that you are working on, right?

@eftshift0 I want to keep commit history from their branch just for a specific directory

History is not kept per directory.

@eftshift0 I know. Do you understand the description of the issue, or should I update it?
